# Postgresql Sum Counts from Results Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a number of locations with people that are at various steps in a step-wise process. I'd like to be able to report the count of people at each step by location and then the total for all locations. So my data looks like this (steps table)

```
| ID | STEP_NUM | LOCATION ID |
-------------------------------
| 1  | 1        | 10          |
| 2  | 1        | 12          |
| 3  | 2        | 4           |
| 4  | 1        | 5           |
| 5  | 1        | 6           |
| 6  | 1        | 3           |
| 7  | 3        | 3           |
```

This stackoverflow question and answer(s) [Postgresql Multiple counts for one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076452/postgresql-multiple-counts-for-one-table) was very useful and I got the summary by location. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT locations.name,
       sum(case when  step_num = 1 then 1 end) as Beginner,
       sum(case when  step_num = 2 then 1 end) as Intermediate,
       sum(case when  step_num = 3 then 1 end) as Expert       
FROM steps
INNER JOIN locations ON steps.location_id = locations.id
GROUP BY locations.name
ORDER BY locations.name ASC
```

How would I also return the total for all locations? For example I would like to get the result:

```
| LOCATION NAME | Beginner | Intermediate | Expert |
----------------------------------------------------
| Uptown        |   5      |              |    1   |
| Downtown      |   2      |       1      |    3   |
| All locations |   7      |       1      |    4   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need rollup operation which is not supported in PostgreSQL yet but [can be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990821/postgresql-equivalent-to-sqlserver-group-by-with-rollup) emulated

```
WITH location AS (
 SELECT locations.name,
   sum(case when  step_num = 1 then 1 end) as Beginner,
   sum(case when  step_num = 2 then 1 end) as Intermediate,
   sum(case when  step_num = 3 then 1 end) as Expert       
 FROM steps
 INNER JOIN locations ON steps.location_id = locations.id
 GROUP BY locations.name
 ORDER BY locations.name ASC
), total AS (
  SELECT 'Total',
         sum(Beginner),
         sum(Intermediate),
         sum(Expert)
  FROM location
) SELECT *
  FROM location
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM total
```

Comment: Thank you @roman-konoval. This looks like the right ingredients but I am getting an unhelpful error from pgAdmin. `ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from unknown to character varying`

Comment: Check that column order is the same for both selects

Comment: I think column order is correct. Is it possible there's a type mismatch or string type mismatch? I noticed if I remove the `SELECT * ... UNION ALL` I get the total row and it is numeric whereas the "location" result is bigInt. Also, I added `as Columnname` to each `sum(Beginner) as Beginner, ...` but that did not fix it either. Same error message. So the Union seems broken for some reason.

Comment: Adding `::text` to make `SELECT 'Total'::text` fixed the issue. Thanks.